# swiperefreshlayout keep refreshing inside onscroll method

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, synchronized, swiperefreshlayout

I'm having a SwipeRefreshLayout and there's a listview inside it.
I want to implement pull up to refresh(since swipe refresh only support pull down refresh), hence did a bit modification on the onscroll method of the list view

```
@Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, final int totalItemCount) {

                  if(firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount >= totalItemCount && totalItemCount != 0 && !swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing() && pagecount > 0){
                      setRefresh();
                  }

//
            }
```

and in the setRefresh method I did this:

[image]

**I even add a synchronized key word to restrict this method to be called once at a time, 
However, in my app I can see the refresh logo keep showing up very quickly and it turns out that the setRefresh keep calling.**

I wonder how does it happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are setting refreshing to false right away instead of in the post delayed bit, when the onScroll method is called it sees the swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing() as false all of the time. Therefore, the setRefresh is called over and over again.

Moving the setRefreshing call to inside the Runnable should fix that issue.